# Django ORM, data that does not match the condition even though filtering is acquired

Tags: python, django

There is a model called `Anayltics` like the following. 
The url field of this model contains various values (e.g '/login', '/sports/1234', '/search').

```
class Analytics(models.Model)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    value = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

I attempted to retrieve only records with url containing strings in category_list below.

```
category_list = ['fashion', 'food', 'sports']

filter_q = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(url__contains=c) for c in category_list))

query = Analytics.objects.filter(filter_q)
```

However, records with unexpected urls, such as url '/login', are also retrieved.

Please tell me where is wrong.

Comment: @Alasdair Oh, I'm sorry. Fixed.

Comment: Your method of reducting `Q()` objects looks OK. I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted, I can't explain why it would return the url `/login`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query.

```
import operator
import functools
from django.db.models import Q

category_list = ['fashion', 'food', 'sports']
query_filter = functools.reduce(operator.or_, (Q(url__icontains = category) for category in category_list))
result = Analytics.objects.filter(query_filter)
```

Comment: This is exactly what the OP posted, which they say doesn't work.

Comment: its not same. **See it once again**. He is using url_contains, instead of using url__icontains ( with double underscore ).

Comment: I'm sorry.It was a mistake that I wrote `url_contains`. Correctly it is `url__contains`. Fixed.

Comment: reduce has moved to functools so you need to import functools and use functools.reduce()